# The type initializer for Test.Program threw an exception

Tags: c#, .net-5

In a .net5.0 project I'm trying to read all mails from txt file, it worked half an hour ago but suddenly when I changed some names for better understanding it stoped working.
I read the txt file location from app.config file and this is the config:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The key Im reading is LokacijaExportanihMailAdresa.
This is the key in app.config;

```
<add key="LokacijaExportanihMailAdresa" value="txt_docs\Mailovi.txt"
```

This is the code with which im trying to read the txt file:

```
class Program
    {
        public static int i = 0;
        public static Timer aTimer = new Timer(Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("VrijemeUMiliSekundama")));
        public static string lokacijaMailova = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("LokacijaExportanihMailAdresa");
        public static string posiljatelj = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Posiljatelj");
        public static string subjekt = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Predmet");
        public static string putanjaDoPoruke = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Poruka");
        public static int imaPrivitak = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ImaAttachment"));
        public static string putanjaDoPrivitka = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Privitak");
        public static string smtpServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SmtpServer");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        logger.Info("Aplikacija je pokrenuta");

        var mailovi = File.ReadAllLines(lokacijaMailova);

        aTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => OnTimedEvent(sender, e, logger, mailovi, i++);

        aTimer.Start();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

}

This is the Error:

```
2021-11-09 13:23:01.6441|Error|MailServis.Program|System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MailServis.Program' threw an exception.
 ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 's')
   at System.Int32.Parse(String s)
   at MailServis.Program..cctor() in C:\Users\djcumbaj\source\repos\MailServis\Program.cs:line 21
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MailServis.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\djcumbaj\source\repos\MailServis\Program.cs:line 32 |
```

But after I put the path directly in File.ReadAllLines it reads the file but the next thing that happens the Timer throws the same exception when i mean the same it's exactly the same.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: You have no value for `ImaAttachment` in config, so when you passing it to `Int32.Parse` it causes exception `Value cannot be null`.

Comment: Yes you were right, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ImaAttachment")` but you have `ImaPrivitak` in the appSettings.